# Why shouldn't RoundTrip modify the request?

Tags: http, go

Why shouldn't RoundTrip modify the request ?

https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go#L103

What happens if http.Request gets modified by a RoundTripper (http.Transport for instance)?

Comment: isn't it just a specification of how it should be implemented?

Comment: Aehm, maybe because users of a RoundTripper may rely on this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awnser is stated in the interface comment https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go#L89

```
A RoundTripper must be safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.
```

If a server gets a request, and starts multiple goroutines, it must be ensured that all requests work on the same input. If a RoundTripper changes the request, it can make already collected data useless (which may not even be noticed)